# SQL ORDER BY 0 (int) needs to be first

Tags: sql, integer, sql-order-by

I am attempting to sort an integer field in ASC order, but it is automatically putting the "0" value near the bottom (just above NULL values).

I am using SQL Server 2005.  I think my DBMS is outdated, because I attempted to use NULLS FIRST, and it was not recognized.

*Edited to show better query (thanks for the quick feedback)

What I want to see:
PriSortOrder/CommunityName
**0/Towson**
1/Atlanta
2/Baltimore
NULL

What I see:
PriSortOrder/CommunityName
1/Atlanta
2/Baltimore
0/Towson
NULL

Query:

```
SELECT PriSortOrder, CommunityName
FROM Communities
WHERE InCatalog=1 
ORDER BY PriSortOrder
```

Comment: That query should not result in that output. Can you create a minimal test-case on http://sqlfiddle.com? Make sure to use the types in th schema and data actually in the database.

Comment: Your query doesn't include the value of the `PrioritySortOrder` column. Are you looking at the values of the `Community` column instead?

Comment: `ORDER BY CASE WHEN PrioritySortOrder=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,PrioritySortOrder`

Comment: I think your data and results are now presented properly (use the **`{}`** above the edit box to indent code-like material - SQL statements and data sets).  Your query is missing its FROM clause, too.  Each DBMS makes its own choice whether to list NULL first or last.  In more recent versions of standard SQL, you can specify NULLS FIRST or NULLS LAST if you wish (and if your DBMS supports it).  You should identify the DBMS you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until you show the `PrioritySortOrder` value as well as the `Community` value, you can't say that the data is in the right (or wrong) order.  For example, if the data is:

```
Community    PrioritySortOrder
0            5
1            0
2            3
NULL         6
```

You will get the output:

```
1
2
0
NULL
```

If the data is:

```
Community    PrioritySortOrder
0            0
1            1
2            2
NULL         3
```

then you will get the result:

```
0
1
2
NULL
```

You can fix your SQL by (adding a `FROM table` clause and) ordering by `Community` instead of `PrioritySortOrder` (though whether the NULL comes first or last depends on your DBMS).